# Solving $\cos(\pi(x-1))=0$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I have a second derivative that I need to use to find inflection points to create a graph. The second derivative is $$f^{\prime\prime}(x)=-4\pi^2\cos(\pi(x-1))$$

So I set the equation to $0$ and solve for $x$

$$-4\pi^2\cos(\pi(x-1))=0$$

I divide by the constant $-4\pi^2$ and get

> $$\cos(\pi(x-1))=0$$

But I am basically stuck at this point. I know I need to take the inverse cosine of both sides. The result I am getting is $x=3/2$, but the answer in the book is $x=1/2$, $3/2$. Can someone help me figure out how to solve the last steps of this problem?

Comment: Are you supposed to find a solution within a given interval?  The equation $\cos[\pi(x - 1)] = 0$ has infinitely many solutions since cosine is periodic.  Also, seeing the statement of the original problem would be helpful.

Comment: $\cos(\pi(x-1))=0$ means $\pi(x-1)=\pi/2\cdot (2n+1)$, where $n$ is an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're looking within $0 \le t \le 2\pi$.

Where does $\cos t = 0$?
At $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$.
Set $\pi(x-1)$ equal to each of these and solve for $x$.  You'll get $3/2$ and $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos\frac{\pi}{2} = \cos\frac{3\pi}{2}$. There is a solution in another region of the 4 quadrants.